# Cell reference in an Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro to write, quite simple.

It just pulls numeric values from a Database and pops them into certain cells.

Problem is, I want the layout and design of the worksheet to be able to be changed without a care of the underlying macro.  So obviously the cell references will change, for the cells that I need to populate with data.

Is there a way to mark a cell - say with "VALUE1" - in the background, and then reference that cell by using "VALUE1" - without needing to know its exact Cell position?  So that its value can be updated - wherever it is on the Work Sheet?

Is there a TAG property or something that could be used? Although a function would have to be written to search through all the TAGs of every cell, but that is OK.

Any ideas?
I think this could be a bonus for any Macro developer :)

Comment: http://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel+vba+named+range

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain? It's unhelpful to downvote without an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office Documentation: [Define and use names in formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx).

Comment: That could be it :) Thanks - will check if it works on single cells but it appears to be the solution

Comment: Do these numbers that you pull from your database match any unique text identifier ?

In that case you could use vlookup() or sumproduct() which can both be used to retrieve values in columns where a cell is matched.

Comment: Not really, because I don't want to bring any lists of data with IDs back into the Excel doc.  Treating it more like a report, with single values here and there.  BUT I do like your alternative method! Thanks